# When do I get a bigger office and can employ more people?

Tags: game-dev-story

In Game Dev Story the number of people is limited by the size of your office, so in the beginning you can only employ 4 people. At some point I was asked if I wanted to move into a bigger office and I'm now wondering what triggers it.

So, what do I have to do to get a bigger office?

Comment: I'd wager its reaching x amount of money by year y but I'm not sure.

Comment: I am not sure either it is not money related this is my 10th play through I'm on yr12 I have 90000 dollars and I have more than 4awards for my game and this was the only time I haven't gotten it so try what I'm Going to do, start over.

Comment: must be $ and time related along with something else. I have $70,000k. Y10M2W4, been in the 2nd office since ~4Y. I have about 6 awards (4 of em are runner up awards...even tho i have gotten one 40 and 3 38pt games. grumble).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm now pretty sure that you get the 3rd office after you win 3 awards for your games. It was triggered for me immediately after the awards ceremony.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, I don't remember either office offer happening after game awards or other events.

Comment: I too got it right after an awards ceremony, except I had way over three awards by that time

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not any 3 awards, but 3 Best Game awards.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't pay attention on my first play-through, but on my second play-through, I noticed the following:

- Y3, M12, W3, I was offered the 2nd office for 6.5k. It allows for 6 employees.
- T10, M12, W3, I was offered the 3rd office for 25k. It allows for 8 employees.

Comment: It might be money related...  I got the 3rd office well before Y10

Comment: its Y4 M2 W3 since the new update

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's money related...Usually I hit the second office in the second or third year, and the third office between the seventh and eighth. I'm pretty sure its the "overall" amount of money you've made, because I've been in situations where I didn't notice the payment, and where the payment has demanded serious sacrifice.